# Zoom-client in Ubuntu Software requires snapd 2.55 but only 2.54 is available, how to install zoom-cllient or upgrade snapd?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, software-center

When I try to install the zoom-client package in Ubuntu Software, I get an error:

Unable to install zoom-client: (null): cannot install "zoom-client": snap "zoom-client" Assumes unsupported features: snapd2.55 (try to refresh snapd)

I have updated my software

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
apt search snapd | grep ^snapd/focal -B 2

snapd/focal-updates,focal-security,now 2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed]
  Daemon and tooling that enable snap packages
```

It seems as if zoom-client requires snapd 2.55 but only 2.54 is available in focal.

How can I install the zoom-client through Ubuntu Software?

Comment: Be patient. 2.55 was released for all supported releases of Ubuntu...but then reverted due to a bug (see https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-2-55-2-stable-release-reverted/29459). When fixed, you will be able to upgrade to 2.55.

Comment: [Why not installing it as deb?](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-zoom-client-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-linux/) Opens faster and respects your theme

Comment: @user535733 Thank you, that explains the reason for this issue.

Comment: @kanehekili Thank you, that solved the issue for now. But when installing deb packages you have to manually upgrade them. For the long run it would be nicer if this is done with apt.

Comment: @Gerben - only chance is to find someone with a ppa containing zoom